# Where did 'you are not your user' originally come from?

Tags: terminology

I been discussing the history of UX - particularly a term I use so much: 'you are not your user'.

Where did this widely used term actually come from??

Far as i can remember/tell/find that source has been lost in the mists of time....but it might just be in such a fundamental book that I've forgotten it...*gasp*

Answer (score 1):

Don Norman has sections in his book [The design of Everyday Things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Design_of_Everyday_Things) called

- 'Designers are not typical users'
- 'The designer's clients are not typical users'

First published 1988, I very much doubt this was the first such observation.

However, it might do for starters and is a good source anyway, even if ironically not the most readable or usable of books!

Comment: Agreed - I remember the entry. It's not the exact phrase either, which is quite specific